# Как найти повторяющееся число в массиве целых чисел?

Tags: javascript

Как найти повторяющееся число в массиве целых чисел? без использование внутренних функций javascript.

```
var let = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5];
```

Comment: внутренние функции javascript - Это какие?

Comment: @Grundy пример для массива внутренние функции js являются [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) .

Comment: Два цикла, счетчик и массив для накопления повторяющихся чисел.  Первый цикл - просто для пробегания по массиву, второй - чтобы еще раз бежать и на каждой итерации сравнивать с текущим элементам первого цикла. Перевд вторым циклом всегда обнуляется счетчик. Если есть совпадение - увеличивать счётчик. После второго цикла смотрим - если счётчик больше 1 - заносим в массив повторяющихся чисел

Comment: А там, случайно, нет дополнительных условий, например, что массив имеет длину `N+1`, а числа в нем - от `1` до `N`? Если да, то все делается за 1 проход по массиву.

Answer (score 1):

1) Использовать словарь, проверяя, нет ли уже такого элемента.
2) Отсортировать "без использование внутренних функций javascript" и пройти, сравнивая соседние.
3) Самое простое и медленное - двойной цикл, сравнение каждого элемента со всеми последующими.